# d3.js Simple LineChart Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a simple line chart based on data in a local JSON format. For the visualization I have to group the original data to the newdata. The grouping works, but unfortunately I cannot use the grouped key from the dates.
I get an error on the browser that says

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

and points to "d3.v3.min.js:1" Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

dataset.js

```js
var dataset = [{
      "key": "DEMO-537",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "TEST1",
        "customfield_12504": 2,
        "customfield_24000": "2023-01-01",
        "status": {
          "name": "bestätigt"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "key": "DEMO-536",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "TEST2",
        "customfield_12504": 13,
        "customfield_24000": "2023-01-01",
        "status": {
          "name": "bestätigt"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "key": "DEMO-535",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "DEMO3",
        "customfield_12504": 12,
        "customfield_24000": "2023-01-01",
        "status": {
          "name": "bestätigt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "DEMO-526",
    "fields": {
      "summary": "TEST4",
      "customfield_12504": 5,
      "customfield_24000": "2022-01-01",
      "status": {
        "name": "bestätigt"
      }
    }
  }];


var newdata = [];
dataset.forEach(issue => {
  key = issue["key"]
  due = issue["fields"]["customfield_24000"]
  value = issue["fields"]["customfield_12504"]
  status = issue["fields"]["status"]["name"]

  newdata.push({
    key: key,
    due: due,
    status: status,
    value: value
  });
});

console.log(newdata);

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.key);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
var LineChart = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(newdata)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

newdata.forEach(issue => {
  key = parseDate(key);
  value = +value;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(newdata, function(d) {
  return d.due;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(newdata, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(newdata));

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(160, 151, 151);
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an updated version of d3, your dataset js is invalid, updated to the d3 v5 syntax draws the scale.

```js
var dataset = [{
  "key": "DEMO-537",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "TEST1",
    "customfield_12504": 2,
    "customfield_24000": "2023-01-01",
    "status": {
      "name": "bestätigt"
    }
  }
}, {
  "key": "DEMO-536",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "TEST2",
    "customfield_12504": 13,
    "customfield_24000": "2023-01-01",
    "status": {
      "name": "bestätigt"
    }
  }
}, {
  "key": "DEMO-535",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "DEMO3",
    "customfield_12504": 12,
    "customfield_24000": "2023-01-01",
    "status": {
      "name": "bestätigt"
    }
  }
}, {
  "key": "DEMO-526",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "TEST4",
    "customfield_12504": 5,
    "customfield_24000": "2022-01-01",
    "status": {
      "name": "bestätigt"
    }
  }
}];


var newdata = [];
dataset.forEach(issue => {
  let key = issue.key;
  let due = issue.fields.customfield_24000;
  let value = issue.fields.customfield_12504;
  let status = issue.fields.status.name;

  newdata.push({
    key: key,
    due: due,
    status: status,
    value: value
  });
});

//console.log(newdata);

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
let margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
let parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
let x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
let y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5);

let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

// Define the line
let valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.key);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

// Adds the svg canvas
let svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
let LineChart = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(newdata)
  .enter()
  .append("g");
/*  key and value are undefined */
newdata.forEach(issue => {
  key = d3.timeParse(issue.key);
  value = +issue.value;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(newdata, function(d) {
  return d.due;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(newdata, function(d) {
  return d.value;
})]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline(newdata));

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgb(160, 151, 151);
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```